# How to check if LWC component is available for Lightning out

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-out, lightning-message-service

I have several components which have complex logic (Platforn events , Message service)

How to check if LWC component/module is available for Lightning out and will work there ?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated .

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are using the standard lightning component, check it from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components), if this is available for Lightning Out. In order for a standard component to be fully available for lightning out, all used standard components should be supported by lightning out.

For example, [lightning-file-upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation) standard component  **is not supported** by lightning out, it is visible, because `Standalone Lightning App` is missing from the list of targets.

[image]

[lightning-button](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/example) standard component **is supported** by lightning out, because `Standalone Lightning App` is present in the list of targets.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helps me .